# How to insert after selecting values from multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO temp_table( 
    case_id, 
    task, 
    Question,
    qa_analyst 
) 
VALUES (
    SELECT 'tt.case_id','tt.Task','abc.questions','tt.qa_analyst'
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT task,questions
        FROM task_questions
    ) abc
    JOIN temp_table tt ON 'abc.task' = 'tt.Task'
)
```

Comment: why not run separate query to retrieve values from other table ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement. And it should be working like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp_table( 
    case_id, 
    task, 
    Question,
    qa_analyst 
)
SELECT tt.case_id, tt.Task, abc.questions, tt.qa_analyst
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT task, questions
    FROM task_questions
) abc
JOIN temp_table tt ON abc.task = tt.Task
```

Comment: I would double check those single quotes...